# limit amount of objects in array of postgresql jsonb_agg

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have this query:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('me_id', me_id)) from message
```

and got the following result:

```
[{"me_id": 2064}, {"me_id": 2065}, {"me_id": 2066}, {"me_id": 2067}, {"me_id": 2068}, {"me_id": 2069}, {"me_id": 2070}, {"me_id": 2071}]
```

so far so good. However I want to LIMIT the amount of objects in the array. For instance to 3. But adding LIMIT 3 is not working.

How can I limit the amount of objects within the array?

EDIT:
@GMB's answer solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a subquery:

```
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('me_id', me_id)) 
from (select * from message order by me_id limit 3) t
```

Comment: Hey that almost did the trick... However, when I want to do a LEFT JOIN now, I get "me_id" is ambiguous: -->

SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', me_id)) 
from (select * FROM message LEFT JOIN message_photo ON (message_photo.me_id = message.me_id) order by message.me_id DESC limit 3) t

Comment: There are two columns called `me_id` in the resultset of the subquery, so that's ambiguous. Use something like `select message.m_id from ...`. Or you can use the `USING` syntax in the join to eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: can you maybe tell me the exact query please? I am a bit overwhelmed by it. I tried by using SELECT message.m_id but then I get this error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "message"

Comment: @André: in your code, just replace `ON (message_photo.me_id = message.me_id)` with  `USING (me_id)`. Or: replace `select *` with `select message.m_id`.

Comment: Thank you very much that solved it !! You were really helpful, thank you very much.